# How do I create create stripped glass effect text in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, typography, posters

I found this image in MoMa website. This poster was designed by Juan Carlos Distéfano in 1964. I try to replicate the effect of the text. Turns out it harder than it looks.

[image: Juan Carlos Distéfano]

Any tips how to achieve this style?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this was drawn entirely by hand as it predates the era of digital design.

You could do something similar using Photoshop and Illustrator together.

First in Photoshop, create a slightly blurred image of some white text on a 50% grey background, make sure the layers are flattened, and that you have the foreground colour set to black and the background colour set to white in the toolbox, then do *Filter > Sketch > Halftone pattern*, with the "Line" pattern selected.

Something like this perhaps

[image]

Then you could copy and paste this into Illustrator, auto trace it, Expand the trace and make a Live Paint object and fill it with the Live Paint Bucket.

Here's the result

[image]

If you want more of those angular diamond shapes, I think you'd have to edit the curves and anchors manually. But any way, it's a good starting point.

Comment: In 1960's many newspapers still used line width modulation half-toning method to print grayscale photos. I guess the artist has manually drawn an enlargened copy of a printing plate of the text which has been in small size and quite unsharp in a photo.

Comment: wow amazing! Thank you so much for the comprehensive reply. This would do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this will have more than one method to achieve your desired outcome.

You could:

**Use the stroke width tool**

Draw out a series of strokes and space them to your liking. Type out your text to act as a guide. Using the width tool (shfit+w on mac) adjust the the stroke to create the desired look. Use your typed text as a guide to follow and remove when done.

If you want to fine tune the look with some unique feature, then outline the strokes and continue.